# Deploy a Maven project with a generated webapp folder to Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, maven, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I am trying to build/deploy/run this maven/apache tomcat project [LODE](https://github.com/essepuntato/LODE).

It's quite the first time I see this style of java web applications. I Followed the instructions provided on the website of this project. Started with maven **clean install**. Then an **src** folder was generated with a **java** folder (containing java classes) and a **webapp** folder (containing web resources) See the photo.

I am used to having a structure where a WebContent folder is there and a WAR file can generated.

[image: photo from my eclipse IDE].

How to deploy this project into apache tomcat and get it to run?

Here is what I tried:

1. I tried generating a war file by editing the **build** section in pom.xml file. However, it did not work.
2. I tried to add the project to Apache Tomcat 9 in my eclipse IDE. However, Tomcat does not believe that this is a web project, so I cannot add it (using right click on Tomcat -> Add/Remove).
3. I tried to take the generated **webapp** folder and deploy it to Tomcat (without eclipse IDE --> tomcat manager 'http://localhost:8081/manager/html' --> Deploy Directory) after creating **WEB-INF/classes** folder and moving the source qualified packages from the generated **src** folder to this folder. This did not work because the java classes were missing (cannot find the java class/package error).

Comment: "I could not" - there's not much explanation there.  I use IntelliJ; not much help with Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

[LODE's README](https://github.com/essepuntato/LODE) clearly says how to lunch the application. Well you don't see a war thus can't deploy on tomcat server.

I found two ways to make it work:

1. `mvn clean jetty:run` from the terminal. This will just work fine (runs on the jetty server).
2. For tomcat server, add `<packaging>war</packaging>` in the pom.xml to generate the war. Then either rename the generated war manually (for example, LODE-1.3-SNAPSHOT.war to lode.war) or use maven plugins to generate the war name. Now deploy this war to your tomcat server as usual.